# Differences between int, int* and int[] with std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, unique-ptr

Since you can do `std::unique_ptr<int> upi{new int}`, I instantly became confused on how to why `std::unique_ptr<int*> upi{new int[42]{}}` doesn't work. Can someone explain the difference between the following snippets?

```
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> upi{new int[42]{}};
    upi.get()[0];
}

// Doesn't work
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> upi{new int[42]{}};
    upi[0];
}

{
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> upi{new int[42]{}};
    upi.get()[0];
}    

{
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> upi{new int[42]{}};
    upi[0];
}     

// Doesn't work
{
    std::unique_ptr<int*> upi{new int[42]{}};
    upi.get()[0];
}      

// Doesn't work    
{
    std::unique_ptr<int*> upi{new int[42]{}};
    upi[0];
}
```

Compiler errors:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:8:20: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
         upi.get()[0];
                    ^
prog.cpp:14:12: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘std::unique_ptr<int>’ and ‘int’)
         upi[0];
            ^
prog.cpp:19:20: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
         upi.get()[0];
                    ^
prog.cpp:29:48: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::unique_ptr<int*>::unique_ptr(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
         std::unique_ptr<int*> upi{new int[42]{}};
                                                ^
prog.cpp:29:48: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/memory:81:0,
                 from prog.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:176:2: note: template<class _Up, class> std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(std::auto_ptr<_Up>&&)
  unique_ptr(auto_ptr<_Up>&& __u) noexcept;
  ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:176:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cpp:29:48: note:   mismatched types ‘std::auto_ptr<_Up>’ and ‘int*’
         std::unique_ptr<int*> upi{new int[42]{}};
                                                ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/memory:81:0,
                 from prog.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:169:2: note: template<class _Up, class _Ep, class> std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(std::unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>&&)
  unique_ptr(unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>&& __u) noexcept
  ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:169:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cpp:29:48: note:   mismatched types ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>’ and ‘int*’
         std::unique_ptr<int*> upi{new int[42]{}};
                                                ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/memory:81:0,
                 from prog.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:160:7: note: std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&&) [with _Tp = int*; _Dp = std::default_delete<int*>]
       unique_ptr(unique_ptr&& __u) noexcept
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:160:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int*’ to ‘std::unique_ptr<int*>&&’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:157:17: note: constexpr std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(std::nullptr_t) [with _Tp = int*; _Dp = std::default_delete<int*>; std::nullptr_t = std::nullptr_t]
       constexpr unique_ptr(nullptr_t) noexcept : unique_ptr() { }
                 ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:157:17: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int*’ to ‘std::nullptr_t’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:151:7: note: std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::pointer, typename std::remove_reference<_To>::type&&) [with _Tp = int*; _Dp = std::default_delete<int*>; std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::pointer = int**; typename std::remove_reference<_To>::type = std::default_delete<int*>]
       unique_ptr(pointer __p,
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:151:7: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:146:7: note: std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::pointer, typename std::conditional<std::is_reference<_Dp>::value, _Dp, const _Dp&>::type) [with _Tp = int*; _Dp = std::default_delete<int*>; std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::pointer = int**; typename std::conditional<std::is_reference<_Dp>::value, _Dp, const _Dp&>::type = const std::default_delete<int*>&]
       unique_ptr(pointer __p,
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:146:7: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:141:7: note: std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::pointer) [with _Tp = int*; _Dp = std::default_delete<int*>; std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::pointer = int**]
       unique_ptr(pointer __p) noexcept
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:141:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int*’ to ‘std::unique_ptr<int*>::pointer {aka int**}’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:135:17: note: constexpr std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr() [with _Tp = int*; _Dp = std::default_delete<int*>]
       constexpr unique_ptr() noexcept
                 ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:135:17: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
prog.cpp:30:20: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
         upi.get()[0];
                    ^
prog.cpp:35:48: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::unique_ptr<int*>::unique_ptr(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
         std::unique_ptr<int*> upi{new int[42]{}};
                                                ^
prog.cpp:35:48: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/memory:81:0,
                 from prog.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:176:2: note: template<class _Up, class> std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(std::auto_ptr<_Up>&&)
  unique_ptr(auto_ptr<_Up>&& __u) noexcept;
  ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:176:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cpp:35:48: note:   mismatched types ‘std::auto_ptr<_Up>’ and ‘int*’
         std::unique_ptr<int*> upi{new int[42]{}};
                                                ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/memory:81:0,
                 from prog.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:169:2: note: template<class _Up, class _Ep, class> std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(std::unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>&&)
  unique_ptr(unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>&& __u) noexcept
  ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:169:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cpp:35:48: note:   mismatched types ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>’ and ‘int*’
         std::unique_ptr<int*> upi{new int[42]{}};
                                                ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/memory:81:0,
                 from prog.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:160:7: note: std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&&) [with _Tp = int*; _Dp = std::default_delete<int*>]
       unique_ptr(unique_ptr&& __u) noexcept
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:160:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int*’ to ‘std::unique_ptr<int*>&&’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:157:17: note: constexpr std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(std::nullptr_t) [with _Tp = int*; _Dp = std::default_delete<int*>; std::nullptr_t = std::nullptr_t]
       constexpr unique_ptr(nullptr_t) noexcept : unique_ptr() { }
                 ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:157:17: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int*’ to ‘std::nullptr_t’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:151:7: note: std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::pointer, typename std::remove_reference<_To>::type&&) [with _Tp = int*; _Dp = std::default_delete<int*>; std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::pointer = int**; typename std::remove_reference<_To>::type = std::default_delete<int*>]
       unique_ptr(pointer __p,
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:151:7: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:146:7: note: std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::pointer, typename std::conditional<std::is_reference<_Dp>::value, _Dp, const _Dp&>::type) [with _Tp = int*; _Dp = std::default_delete<int*>; std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::pointer = int**; typename std::conditional<std::is_reference<_Dp>::value, _Dp, const _Dp&>::type = const std::default_delete<int*>&]
       unique_ptr(pointer __p,
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:146:7: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:141:7: note: std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::pointer) [with _Tp = int*; _Dp = std::default_delete<int*>; std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::pointer = int**]
       unique_ptr(pointer __p) noexcept
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:141:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int*’ to ‘std::unique_ptr<int*>::pointer {aka int**}’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:135:17: note: constexpr std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr() [with _Tp = int*; _Dp = std::default_delete<int*>]
       constexpr unique_ptr() noexcept
                 ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:135:17: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
prog.cpp:36:12: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘std::unique_ptr<int*>’ and ‘int’)
         upi[0];
            ^
```

Comment: Could you please never ever say "doesn't work" again?

Comment: `int` is not `int*`. What you have doesn't *compile*, much less "work".

Comment: It means I get compiler error.s

Comment: ALWAYS post the actual errors you are getting, and show which lines are producing the errors.

Comment: +1 for posting errors.  To improve further, curate the errors a bit.  For example, the first warning: you understand it?  Maybe connect the errors to the code by putting the error next to the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 std::unique_ptr<int> upi{new int[42]{}};
```

has undefined behavior. You're allocating memory using `new[]` and the `unique_ptr` is going to call `delete`, and not `delete[]`, in its destructor.

```
upi[0];
```

doesn't compile because the `unique_ptr::operator[]` overload only exists for the `unique_ptr<T[]>` partial specialization.

```
std::unique_ptr<int*> upi{new int[42]{}};
```

doesn't compile because the `unique_ptr` constructor is expecting an `int**`, but you're passing it an `int*`. If it did compile, it would've had undefined behavior due to the same reason as in the previous case.

---

You should use

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> upi{new int[42]{}};
upi.get()[0] = 0;  // this works
upi[0] = 0;        // and so does this
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the array version of `unique_ptr`, you have to specify an array type (ie, `int[]` instead of `int`) in the first template parameter, otherwise you are using the pointer version instead.

An `int[]` can degrade into a `int*`.  You can pass `new int[]` to the constructor of `unique_ptr<int>` since it takes an `int*` as input, but then you cannot access the `upi[]` operator because it does not exist in that version of `unique_ptr`, only when using `unique_ptr<int[]>` instead.

Comment: How do I write a specialization for the pointer version?

Comment: If you want to use `std::unique_ptr<int*>`, you have to provide an `int**` to the constructor, such as `std::unique_ptr<int*> upi{new int*[42]{}};` But of course that is wrong, because `delete[]` will not be used. You would have to use `std::unique_ptr<int*[]> upi{new int[42]{}};` instead.

Comment: To make `upi[0]` work for `std::unique_ptr<int>`

Comment: `upi[]` does not work for `std::unique_ptr<int>` because `operator[]` simply does not exist in that version. Don't even try to use it.  It is wrong to put an `int[]` into a `unique_ptr<int>` anyway. You have to use `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` instead. That is how it is meant to be used. Do not circumvent that.